# Custom variable in the scope of the screen iOS - Matomo SDK IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, matomo

I added custom variable in the scope of the screen on android using matomo.

Example in android:

```
TrackHelper.track(mVisitVars.toVisitVariables()).screen(screenPath).title(title)
.variable(1, "variable 1", getCustomVariableA())
.variable(2, "variable 2", getCustomVariableB())
.with(tracker);
```

but on iOS I'm having a problem with this implementation. How to add custom variable in the scope of the screen on iOS?